# Error with Gradle: Could not get unknown property 'project' for ProductFlavor_Decorated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've searched everywhere for this issue and I haven't found a solution for this. I upgraded Gradle to version 6.7.1. While trying to sync Gradle for the first time after upgrading, I received this error:

```java
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'project' for ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=flavor1, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=[], buildConfigFields={}, resValues={}, proguardFiles=[], consumerProguardFiles=[], manifestPlaceholders={}, wearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:62)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at de.triplet.gradle.play.PlayPublisherPlugin$_apply_closure2.doCall(PlayPublisherPlugin.groovy:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:285)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate._configure(NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:65)
    at build_vakvk2514duks3dkwbm106jz$_run_closure2$_closure14.doCall({project-directory}/app/build.gradle:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:103)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CommonExtensionImpl.productFlavors(CommonExtensionImpl.kt:197)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.productFlavors(BaseAppModuleExtension.kt)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension_Decorated.productFlavors(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:56)
    at build_vakvk2514duks3dkwbm106jz$_run_closure2.doCall({project-directory}/app/build.gradle:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.configureExtension(DefaultConvention.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.access$500(DefaultConvention.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
    at build_vakvk2514duks3dkwbm106jz.run({project-directory}/app/build.gradle:22)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 140 more
```

this is the product flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "brand", "environment"
productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "brand"
            playAccountConfig = playAccountConfigs.defaultAccountConfig
            applicationId "com.flavor1.foo"
            buildConfigField("String", "productName", "\"Flavor 1\"")
        }
        flavor2 {
            dimension "brand"
            playAccountConfig = playAccountConfigs.defaultAccountConfig
            applicationId "com.flavor2.foo"
            buildConfigField("String", "productName", "\"Flavor 2\"")
        }
        iat {
            dimension "environment"
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IAT_ENVIRONMENT", "true")
        }
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IAT_ENVIRONMENT", "false")
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what caused it to crash all of a sudden, it was working fine with Gradle version 5.6.4.

Comment: What is in line 81 of `$projectDir/app/build.gradle`? Can you maybe provide a [mcve]?

Comment: From my perspective, it's hard to say what is the problem because I can't reproduce the issue.
It seems that the code you have provided is not enough.
Could be related to some additional configuration in your project.
I think that providing a simple demo project where we can reproduce the issue would be very helpful.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was related to the Gradle Play Publisher. I removed the plugin and the project is now building.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was related to Gradle Play Publisher. I removed all lines related to `com.github.triplet.play` and now it is building. Hope this helps anyone who also had issues like I did.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: you may have already done some of this but I am going to include all of it just in case

Create a new file called "gradle.properties" at the root of the project.
Copy and Paste these Configurations that fit your needs:

- ./gradle.properties
- ./app/build.gradle
- Firebase - google-services.json
- Remote configs
- Protocol version

---

### Configs in gradle.properties

Sample Configuration

```
ORG="SG_OTC"
STORE_URL="<Play store URL>"
PRIVACY_URL="<Privacy policy URL>"

SERVICE_FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID=771579
SERVICE_FOREGROUND_CHANNEL_ID="OpenTrace Updates"
SERVICE_FOREGROUND_CHANNEL_NAME="OpenTrace Foreground Service"

PUSH_NOTIFICATION_ID=771578
PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME="OpenTrace Notifications"

#service configurations
SCAN_DURATION=8000
MIN_SCAN_INTERVAL=36000
MAX_SCAN_INTERVAL=43000

ADVERTISING_DURATION=180000
ADVERTISING_INTERVAL=5000

PURGE_INTERVAL=86400000
PURGE_TTL=1814400000
MAX_QUEUE_TIME=7000
BM_CHECK_INTERVAL=540000
HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL=900000
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=6000
BLACKLIST_DURATION=100000

FIREBASE_REGION = "<Your Firebase region>"

STAGING_FIREBASE_UPLOAD_BUCKET = "opentrace-app-staging"
STAGING_SERVICE_UUID = "17E033D3-490E-4BC9-9FE8-2F567643F4D3"

V2_CHARACTERISTIC_ID = "117BDD58-57CE-4E7A-8E87-7CCCDDA2A804"

PRODUCTION_FIREBASE_UPLOAD_BUCKET = "opentrace-app"
PRODUCTION_SERVICE_UUID = "B82AB3FC-1595-4F6A-80F0-FE094CC218F9"

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

---

### Build Configurations in build.gradle

Change the package name and other configurations accordingly such as the `resValue` in in the different settings in `buildTypes` For example,

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "FIREBASE_UPLOAD_BUCKET", STAGING_FIREBASE_UPLOAD_BUCKET
            buildConfigField "String", "BLE_SSID", STAGING_SERVICE_UUID

            String ssid = STAGING_SERVICE_UUID
            versionNameSuffix "-debug-${getGitHash()}-${ssid.substring(ssid.length() - 5,ssid.length() - 1 )}"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "OpenTrace Debug"
            applicationIdSuffix "stg"
        }
```

> Values such as STAGING_FIREBASE_UPLOAD_BUCKET, STAGING_SERVICE_UUID have been defined in gradle.properties as described above.

---

### Firebase and google-services.json

Setup Firebase for the different environment. Download the google-services.json for each of the environments and put it in the corresponding folder.

Debug: ./app/src/debug/google-services.json

Production: ./app/src/release/google-services.json

The app currently relies on Firebase Functions to work. More information can be obtained by referring to [opentrace-cloud-functions](https://github.com/opentrace-community/opentrace-cloud-functions).

---

### Remote Config

Remote config is used for retrieving the "Share" message used in the app. The key for it is "ShareText". If it is unable to be retrieved, it falls back to R.string.share_message

---

### Protocol Version

Protocol version used should be 2 (or above) Version 1 of the protocol has been deprecated

---

from [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/opentrace-community/opentrace-android#configs-in-gradleproperties)

Comment: Could you elaborate how that answers the question? This looks unrelated to me …

Comment: @Chriki you need to add this to your code in a new file; gradle.properties for the first, build.gradle for the second, and so on to configure the program